# Combining multiple spreadsheets into one

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I have .pdf file which consists of 11 pages.
My goal is to convert it into one Excel spreadsheet.
Unfortunately I failed to delete 'breakpoints' in .pdf file.
I have Nuance PDF Converter Professional but it did not allow me to do it.
Than I tried to combine from Excel combine 11 spreadsheet into one using 'move or copy ...' operation but it still moved only one page and not 11.
In my case Excel is integrated with Nuance PDF and I was able to open .pdf file directly from Excel and tried to change various setting but it again created 11 spreadsheets and not one as I wanted.
Could someone provide me the path to do it?
Thanks

Comment: can you get the original data that was used to make the pdf and use that instead?

Comment: Sure. I have original .pdf file. The goal is to get data from .pdf into spreadsheet. I could do it but since .pdf has 11 pages it was converted into workbook with 11 spreadsheets which I want to combine into one.

Comment: code like this will let you loop through all files in a folder, and potentially run code to copy the data from each file and paste together. But it's hard to suggest how the copy paste code might go without seeing your data. I asked about the original data, meaning whatever spreadsheet or database was used to make the pdf, because converting from pdf to Excel is always going to cause issues and it is better to not deal with pdf at all if possible.

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood you. Unfortunately in this case I don’t have access to ‘original ‘ sources hence I have to deal with.pdf. Sure I can copy/paste 11 times into one sheet but I am looking for some ‘easier/faster ‘ solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved my issue with workaround
I converted .pdf to text file. 
After that I was able to source it into Excel as one sheet with no problem.